# Windows Settings > Storage "Other" listing is completely inaccurate

Tags: windows-10, storage

I have a ACER Laptop with Windows 10 home version 1607.  2GB RAM, and 30GB hard drive.

Of that 30GB I have the following breakdown (from Strorage in Settings):

```
13.4G System and Reserved
6.24G Apps and Games
4.09G "Other"
```

All the other categories are insignificant/small.  Clicking on "Other", I see a list of folders, but they do not anywhere near add up to 4.09G.  Where can I find these files?  I'm inclined to believe this UI is useless as I can't solve the problem it's stating I have.

Comment: One thing to also note, if you only have 2gb of ram, Is that you may be building a very large paging file. This file is invisible by default but called "pagefile.sys". By default, it is located at `c:\pagefile.sys`. Enable hidden files/system files and you should be able to see it to check if it is massive,

Comment: I'd suggest downloading [WinDirStat](https://windirstat.net/). It will scan your hard drive and show a visual representation of the sizes of all the files and folders on your hard drive.  Makes it much easier to locate unusually large files or folders.

Answer (score 1):

Click "Other" and it will drill into what is falling into that category. There will be a list of paths which can also be clicked to see the actual files at those paths. Each category can be drilled into and reveal details in this manner. Or try a 3rd part disk analyzer like https://windirstat.net/

Comment: Actually, all of those folders that it lists under "Other" - when I click on them - show the accurate size.  But what I'm saying is all those folders don't nearly add up to the 4.09G that the heading says.  I would accept your answer if nobody else just says "Yeah, it's just a Windows thing, you can't rely on and it's not helpful to find what it refers to" :)